# Substitute all non letters/numbers with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `'hello (new)'` and I would like to remove all non numbers and letters. One way to do this is by finding all letters and joining them:

```
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-0]', 'hello (new)'))
'hellonew'
```

How would I do the reverse, that is, subtituting all non-characters to `''`? So far I had:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'hello (new)')
' (new)'
```

But it's off a bit.

Comment: Try using `\W+` See https://regex101.com/r/dkqgiC/1 If you want to keep the underscores use `[\W_]+`

Comment: Try this `r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a negated character class instead and remove the anchor at the front:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9]+', '', 'hello (new)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match any non word character 1+ times using `\W+`.

If you want to keep the underscore which is matched by \w you could use a character class `[\W_]+`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/IQ3O4c)

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'\W+', '', 'hello (new)'))
```

Output

```
hellonew
```